# Arangodb: --database.directory setting not respected when giving instance a name

Tags: arangodb

When I run arangod like this:

```
arangod --supervisor --daemon --pid-file some_file \
        --configuration some_file.conf \
        single_instance
```

then

```
--database.directory
```

option is ignored and

```
/var/tmp/single_instance
```

directory containing

```
├── single_instance_db
    ├── databases
    ├── journals
    ├── LOCK
    ├── rocksdb
    ├── SERVER
    └── SHUTDOWN
```

is created.

But when I run arangod like this:

```
arangod --supervisor --daemon --pid-file some_file \
        --configuration some_file.conf
```

then

```
--database.directory
```

option is honoured.

Why ?
(Is it some bug ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things arangod prints during the startup for me is:

```
changed working directory for child process to '/var/tmp'
```

This is done by the supervisor before it forks the child.

Since you gave it the relative directory `single_instance`, this database directory is created in the then current working directory `/var/tmp/` resulting in a total database directory of `/var/tmp/single_instance`.

If you want a specific directory in that situation, you should specify an absolute path like `/var/lib/arangodb/single_instance`.

Comment: Silly me: arangod [options] database-directory - so the last argument is database directory, not the instance name as I thought - and it overrides the one specified with --database.directory.